# Can the ssh config file read from another file?

Tags: bash, ssh

I am wanting to modify my `~/.ssh/config` file so that it reads IP address from a text file. For example:

```
Host prod-app
    HostName ip-address-here
    User root
    Port 22
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my-key
```

Since my EC2 instances have different public IP addresses after deployments, I am trying to figure out a way that I can just simply have this read from a text file. So rather than above, it would look something like this:

```
Host prod-app
    HostName $(cat $HOME/Documents/app_prod.txt)
    User root
    Port 22
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my-key
```

That doesn't work because of the following error:

```
/Users/nutella/.ssh/config line 33: garbage at end of line; "$HOME/Documents/app_prod.txt)"
```

Is there an easy way to get this work or a better way by chance?

Comment: Have you considered using a dns name to point to the instance instead?

Comment: Haven't created anything in the DNS records just to avoid having others being able to pull this from DNS queries. Also I believe the instances will constantly shuffle out since we're using spot instances.

Comment: the default DNS name changes. you can create your own dns record and point it at the instance, as well as update where it points to in your deployment process

Comment: Gotcha. This would have to be made public right? So meaning anyone else would be able to just query the DNS records? Can protect it with security access groups of course, but just was hoping to avoid exposing anything publicly, even to IPs that are protected by security groups (just in case of a mistake of course)

Comment: Is it an option to put `a.b.c.d app_prod` in /etc/hosts and put `HostName app_prod` in .ssh/config ?

Comment: What I ended up doing was creating a script to auto replace this in my ssh config file. I think your approach would have been just as sufficient too @Philippe

Answer (score 3):

You could use an include statement:

```
Host prod-app
    include ~/Documents/app_prod.txt
    User root
    Port 22
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my-key
```

app_prod.txt:

```
HostName  192.0.2.1
```